# Kentico SmartSearch, Custom Results

Tags: kentico

i'm using Kentico Smart Search but im looking to build a reference table, basically to boost particular pages for particular phrases i.e.

if user searches for "XYZ" result = "www.examplesearchresult.com"
if user searches for "ABC" result = "www.secondexampleresult.com"

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks
Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other way how to achieve this would be in modifying the dataset of results. You will check the search term and if it will fit your rules, you will access the returned datset with results (\CMSModules\SmartSearch\Controls\SearchResults.ascx.cs in Search() method) and add column(s) with your desired items.

Answer (score 0):

If you're searching for specific document types, you can extend the document type by adding another field and allowing it to be searchable. Then you can alter your lucene query to include that field as well.

Comment: thanks for your help, are you suggesting that i create custom fields for the documents i want to add a reference for & then include the reference in there? how would this guarantee it came up as the top result?